# Using structs in C# to read data

Tags: c#

Say I have a struct defined as such

```
struct Student
{
  int age;
  int height;
  char[] name[12];
}
```

When I'm reading a binary file, it looks something like

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
Student someStudent;

int num_students = myFile.readUInt32();
for (int i = 0; i < num_students; i++)
{
   // read a student struct
}
```

How can I write my struct so that I just need to say something along the lines of

```
someStudent = new Student();
```

So that it will read the file in the order that the struct is defined, and allow me to get the values as needed with syntax like

```
someStudent.age;
```

I could define the Student as a class and have the constructor read data and populate them, but it wouldn't have any methods beyond getters/setters so I thought a struct would be more appropriate.

Or does it not matter whether I use a class or struct? I've seen others write C code using structs to read in blocks of data and figured it was a "good" way to do it.

Comment: [`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx) is where you would start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a binary file using c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463476/how-to-read-a-binary-file-using-c)

Comment: For some reason the accepted answer there makes it seems like using structs would make the code harder to read. I mean, there's all those extra things going on.

Comment: While you can read a struct in C# "the C++ way", it's complicated. Is there any reason you can't just read the fields one by one, using the relevant methods in BinaryReader?

Comment: Not really. I was just experimenting with ways of trying to make my code easier to follow. When someone goes to that loop and sees me just reading a set of "Student" structs they'll know that it's just student data there. They might not even care what a Student is composed of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to serialize / deserialize the struct**

If you want to read/write the entire struct to a binary file (serialization), I suggest you look at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/629120/141172

Or, if it is an option for you, follow @Marc's advice and use a cross-platform serializer.  Personally I would suggest [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) which just happens to have been written by @Marc.

**If you are loading from an arbitrary file format**

Just like a *class*, a *struct* can have a constructor that accepts multiple parameters.  In fact, it is generally wise to *not* provide setters for a *struct*.  Doing so allows the values of the *struct* to be changed after it is constructed, which generally leads to programming bugs because many developers fail to appreciate the fact that *struct* is a value type with value semantics.

I would suggest providing a single constructor to initialize your *struct*, reading the values from the file into temporary variables, and then constructing the *struct* with a constructor.

```
public stuct MyStruct
{
    public int Age { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    private char[] name;
    public char[] Name 
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length > 12) throw new Exception("Max length is 12");
            name = value;
        }
    }
    public MyStruct(int age, int height, char[] name)
    {
    }
}
```

To dig further into the perils of mutable structs (ones that can be changed after initialized) I suggest

[Why are mutable structs “evil”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Comment: I am not sure what "constructing the struct with a constructor" would look like. Is it the same constructor that initialized the struct and read temporary values?

Answer (score 1):

There is not, AFAIK, a low-level direct-layout struct reader built into .NET. You would want want to look at BinaryReader, reading each field in turn? Basically, ReadInt32() twice, and ReadChars(). Pay particular attention to the **encoding** of the character data (ASCII? UTF8? UTF-16?) and the *endianness* of the integers.

Personally, I'd look more at using a dedicated cross-platform serializer!

Comment: A serializer like... protobuf-net?  Great implementation of protocol buffers.  Thanks for doing that.